# Change format (need to have a comma in my data) Excel 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I calculate data directly in a userform and I transfer my data into a table afterwards. In my userform the numbers are good, but not in the table. I would like that my data (Double) appear with a comma in my table. For now, my data are in the table without comma. For example, my data is `441 666 666 666 667` instead of `4,41666666666667` ... I think that I have to change the format? Can anyone enlighten me on this subject please? Thank you.

Code example:

```
Private Sub tbxHours_Change()

Dim rate As String
Dim hours As String

rate = Replace(tbxRate .Value, ".", ",")
hours = Replace(tbxHours .Value, ".", ",")

If StrComp(rate , "") = 0 Then rate = "0"
If StrComp(hours , "") = 0 Then hours = "0"

tbxCostRate.Value = CStr(CDbl(rate) * CDbl(hours))

End sub
```

Comment: why are the rate and hours defined as string variables? these are clearly numerical values.

Comment: is that value 4 hours 25 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your code completely, but this is the format you want to apply to your values.

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the comma as the decimal delimiter, correct? If so, make sure that the settings are correct in excel. See [Microsoft Change Character for Delimiter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

This can be done this with the VBA Format() function:

```
'Comma as the Decimal Delimiter
tbxCostRate.Value = Format(CDbl(rate) * CDbl(hours), "#.##0,00")
'Comma as the Thousands delimiter
tbxCostRate.Value = Format(CDbl(rate) * CDbl(hours), "#,##0.00")
```

*Note: the rate probably shouldn't be converted to a string if the data is numeric

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
tbxCostRate.Value = Format CStr(CDbl(rate) * CDbl(hours)), "Standard")
```